# Aggregating Websocket Data in Rails and Saving Once Per Minute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket

I have rapid price data coming in through a websocket. I want to serialize it to the correct format and rebroadcast this to a different websocket to my Ember frontend. I also want to aggregate the data once per minute and save this to the rails database.

Is the serializing/rebroadcast and the aggregation/caching possible in rails? I would like to know if I am going about it in the right way. If so, what caching mechanism is there and how can I make this happen accurately once per minute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, I found it easy to dump the websocket data in InfluxDB which has aggregation and self deletion of old data. I haven't interfaced with rails, but a simple node.js script was easy following their sample code.

Huge job to do this with rails/redis or something.